# What is the reason of java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when calling a SOAP WS?

Tags: web-services, soap

I am just tryig to understand the Soap WS. So I just write some simple classes as follow. but when I deploy this application in GlassFish and test it, the server returns the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. Can anybody say what the problem is?

```
@WebService
public class AuthorWS {
AuthorService authorService = new AuthorService();

@WebMethod
public Author getAuthorById(int authorId) {
    return authorService.getAuthorById(authorId);
}

@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    return authorService.getAllAuthors();
}
}
```

Service Class:

```
public class AuthorService {
AuthorDAO authorDAO = new AuthorDAO();
public Author getAuthorById(int authorId){

    return authorDAO.getAuthorById(authorId);
}
public ArrayList<Author> getAllAuthors(){
    return authorDAO.getAllAuthors();
}
}
```

DAO Class:

```
public class AuthorDAO {

public Author getAuthorById(int authorId){
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(Author.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("authorId", authorId));
    return (Author) criteria.uniqueResult();

}
public ArrayList<Author> getAllAuthors(){
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(Author.class);
    return (ArrayList<Author>) criteria.list();
}
```

Exception:

'Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:313) ... 32 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.hojat.LibrarySoapWS.ws.AuthorWS Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure. at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy312.getAllAuthors(Unknown Source)'

Comment: look further down the stack trace, the reason will be in 'Caused By' somewhere

Comment: I already added the stack trace. But I could not figure it out. Could you please take a look at it and give me a hint?

Comment: The stack trace is unreadable, please format it so that each line is visible

Comment: You can read it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server side, as you can see from the stack trace

```
: Client received SOAP Fault from server:
 com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: 
Error creating managed object for class: 
class com.hojat.LibrarySoapWS.ws.AuthorWS 
Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
```

So check the server log.